# Unity: Constructor injection with mutiple constructors

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unity-container, constructor-injection

I'm trying to inject an EF ObjectContext using Unity constructor injection.
My attemp is to register the type in the bootsprapper like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    Container.RegisterType<ObjectContext, MyObjectContext>(new InjectionConstructor());
}
```

EF creates mutiple constructors which look like these

```
public MyObjectContext() : base("name=MyObjectContext", "MyObjectContext")
public MyObjectContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "MyObjectContext")
public MyObjectContext(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "MyObjectContext")
```

When debugging my code Unity throws a ResolutionFailedException telling me "The type MyObjectContext has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate." at the time when a new class that has the following constructor is resolved.

```
public MainViewModel(UnityContainer container, MyObjectContext entities)
```

As far as I know using `RegisterType` with `new InjectionConstructor()` as argument ensures that the default parameterless constructor is called (thats what I want). Why can't Unity resolve the type as expected? Do I miss anything?

Best Regards

Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your registration looks right.  You sure the registration code is getting called?  Try putting a breakpoint on it.

(Off topic: why are you passing your container to your viewmodel?)

Comment: I mark this as an answer because it led me to the solution. It seems that Unity had some issues resolving the type because I had registered it at the wrong place. I passed the container because I thought I would need it to resolve registered instances/types across projects (shell, modules, infrastructure etc.) but that doesn't seem to be the right/working way.